# os.path.join with the import statement

Tags: python

I would like to simplify as much as possible the syntax and the number of lines, so I was wondering why the following statement is an erro:

```
from os.path.join(path1,path2,filename) import *
```

the `os.path.join` seems not to run with the `import` statement.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: That's not how import statements work. You need to import the method, and then run it. In this case, that could look like `from os import path` then `path.join(path1,path2,filename)`

Comment: What is the error? We need to know that too help.

Comment: Python doesn’t import from paths. It imports from module names.

Comment: The question makes sense, and should not be downvoted as it is being.

Answer (score 2):

Python's import statement needs a "module name", not a file path to work. The way to import using a variable is to use the `importlib.import_module` built-in function.
You have, of course, to use your filesystem "path" directory names to package names, and the top most of which must be "visible" in the PythonPath. The  `[:-3]` part is just there to strip the `.py` part, but you can just use the modulename without the ".py" to startwith.

```
from importlib import import_module

module = importmodule('.'.join([path1, path2, filename[:-3]])
for attr in dir(module):
    globals()[attr] = getattr(module, attr)
```

However, as you see, you will populate your namespace with names you don't know which they are, and thus, you can't have program code using those names - what makes it kind of pointless. It may be more useful to simply create a new dictionary with the attributes of your imported module:

```
namespace = {}

for attr in dir(module):
    namespace[attr] = getattr(module, attr)
```

so you can introspect what was imported and call/use those values.

Now, if your "path1", and "path2" are not a package, and you really want to just import module from an arbitrary location, what is needed is to have the location inserted in the Pythonpath bedore calling `import_module`. The Pythonpath, however, is a simple list located at `sys.path` - just insert the full-folder path there (and pop it later if you want):

```
def import_path(path1, path2, module_name, namespace=None):
    import sys
    from importlib import import_module
    from pathlib import Path # new code should use this instead of "os.path" stuff
    path = Path(path1).joinpath(path2)
    name = module_name[-3:] if module_name.endswith(".py") else module_name
    try:
        sys.path.insert(0, str(path))
        module = import_module(name)
    finally:
        sys.path.remove(str(path))
    if namespace is None:
        namespace = sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals()
    for name in dir(module):
        namespace[name] = getattr(module, name)
```

(One can also use directly the `__import__` function without needing to to use `importlib.import_module`, but its use is not advised in the documentation. Among other things when using the single argument form `__import__("path1.path2.module")` will return `path1` not `module`.)